# void bool toogle C++

Tags: c++

i make a SPRX for PS3 in C++, i'm very bad on C++ and i want make a void when i press a specific button on my controller, it's enable the void and when i press it again it's disable it

My Main Code:

```
void Menu(uint64_t args) {
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            if (Functions::InGame)
            {
                if (buttons::IsMCButtonPressed(buttons::L1) && buttons::IsMCButtonPressed(buttons::R1))
                {
                    //VOID SPEED TOGGLE WHEN L1 + R1 is enabled
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My void for SPEED:

```
void SPEED(bool enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
            *(char*)0x003ABD51 = 0xFFFFFF;
        } else {
            *(char*)0x003ABD51 = 0x26AD89;
        }
    }
```

I want when I press `L1 + R1` it's enable `*(char*)0x003ABD51 = 0xFFFFFF;` and when press it again (disable) it's changed to: `*(char*)0x003ABD51 = 0x26AD89;`

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? And why do you write exacly to these addresses?

Comment: This addresse is for change the speed, i just change the byte for enable / reset to default. My problem is i cant enable it but not disable

Answer (score 0):

```
void Menu(uint64_t args) {
    {
bool speed_state = false;
        for (;;)
        {
            if (Functions::InGame)
            {
                if (buttons::IsMCButtonPressed(buttons::L1) && buttons::IsMCButtonPressed(buttons::R1))
                {
                    //VOID SPEED TOGGLE WHEN L1 + R1 is enabled
                    speed_state = !speed_state;
                    SPEED(speed_state);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
void SPEED(bool enabled) {
uint32_t* speed = 0x003adb51;
        if (enabled) {
            *speed = 0xFFFFFF;
        } else {
            *speed = 0x26AD89;
        }
    }
```

some comments:
- speed_state - it changes value at each L1+R1.
- uint32_t* speed - pointer to memory with size 32bit, you should choose the size for your case (I think, 'char' (it is 8 bit size) will not be able to  contain your values).